# Cant' access async nested json in state, get the error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'XX' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I got data from axios and store it in the state, I'm not able to get the nested attribute.

```
{
  "a":"hi",
  "b":1,
  "c": {
    "c1":3,
    "c2":"hello",

  }
 }
```

For example, if the response is this and I use  `this.setState({test:res.data});`

I can use this.state.test.a or this.state.test.b to get "hi" and 1, and I can also use this.state.c to get c, but I'm not able to get `c1` or `c2` by `this.state.c.c1`. It seems I can add an extra  `this.setState({datac:res.data.c});` and then use `this.state.datac.c1` to reach `c1`, but may I know why? I already put the whole object to test, why can't access the nested element? But I remember sometimes I can access to the nested element......  And what would be a good way to do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: i think you need to make a deep copy of the object. could you try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data))` ?
see more here: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript

Comment: show please your entire component

Comment: can you provide codesandbox link for this? might be typeof `c` is not an object

Comment: And I feel strange since if I request the api for total cards, it response basically the same but just a list of all the card object, I can access web_links like this, but if I send api request for a single card, it does not work like that

Comment: Thank you so much! The deep copy still not work.  @rebecca

Comment: The json is here: codepen.io/yingli40604345/pen/zVgPwP?editors=1010 I can't access for example this.state.data.program_asset.web_link .  @AviatorX Thank you so much

Comment: And the component is this: codepen.io/yingli40604345/pen/ageVVG?editors=0010 . I can access it if I add extra web_link state .  @OlegI Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

And I just found that if I pass the nested json as props to functional component, the component can use it, but if I pass it as props to class component, I get the error. Nor sure why.